# Std mac / Windows issues

Tags: c++, std

I want to make my c++ program cross-platform and it uses std::cos and std::sin, I have no issues with it on windows but it doesn't work on mac, why is this and how can I solve the problem?

It gives out this error "no member named cos in std"

Thanks

Comment: Try including the `<cmath>` header file if you haven't already.

Comment: It gives out this error "no member named cos in std" when compiling

Comment: No I haven't included <cmath>

Comment: @HenryLeBerre Then do so, as that's where the functions you are using are declared.

Comment: Thanks, I have and it is now working but why does it work on windows and not on mac? Thanks!

Comment: Same issue as [Why does omission of "#include " only sometimes cause compilation failures?](//stackoverflow.com/q/9539650)